# Rename classes with powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget-package

I created a package which extended the DatabaseContext from .Net. So i tried to make my project use the new DatabaseContext when the package was installed. So i used a .pp file but it replaced all contents. (see image below)

[image]

But i only want to rename all the class usages of: `IdentityDbContext` to `IdentityDbContextExtDbConfiguraion`. i think i should achieve this with the powershell script but i could not find any tutorial which could help me any further on this. (I could only find file renaming examples).

Is there a way to achieve this in powershell or are there better options?

Thanks!

I tried something like:

```
ForEach ($item in Get-ChildItem -recurse) { 
$item.Name >> "test.txt"
#text = text + $item.Name + ", "
} 
#$path = ".\Models\IdentityModels.cs"
#$word = "IdentityDbContext<"
#$replacement = "IdentityDbContextExtDbConfiguration<"

#$text = get-content $path
#$newText =  $text -replace $word,$replacement
#$newText > $path
```

i want to find and replace for each .cs file in the project, how should i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine replacing all instances of `IdentityDbContext<` with `IdentityDbContextExtDbConfiguration<`, you could easily achieve this using PowerShell. Just use a script like the following:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.cs)
{
    $filename = $file.FullName; 
    $content = Get-Content $filename -Raw -Encoding UTF8
    $replacedContent = $content -replace 'IdentityDbContext<','IdentityDbContextExtDbConfiguration<' 
    $replacedContent | Set-Content $filename -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: Thx! how should i make it only replace stuff in its own project, not intire solution? I tried `foreach ($file in $project | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.cs)` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` is the equivalent of the `dir` command in the command prompt (you can even use the `dir` alias instead of `Get-ChildItem` if you want). Getting it to only replace the text in the files which belong to a specific folder is as easy as `cd`ing into the directory of your project before you run the above command.